# How to write \LaTeX properly?

Tags: symbols

I just started learning LaTeX, and I'm having trouble to write a symbol, LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/how-to-get-latex-symbol-in-document?rq=1

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Hi. I've already seen that post and I'm still stuck.

Comment: You should write `\LaTeX`, not `\LaTex`.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke What a silly question I had..... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write it as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]