# How could I write my name, for example, to look like the \LaTeX logo?

Tags: fonts, fun, logos

How could I write my name, for example, in a `\LaTeX` style? It is just interesting, as in Google all other things pop up when I try to search for an answer!

Comment: Are you asking about handwritten fonts?  If so, see http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html for various LaTeX options,

Comment: You'd have to provide us with some context as to what you mean by "a LaTeX style" for "your name".

Comment: in your texmf `tex\latex\base\latex.ltx` search for `\LaTeX`

Comment: @touhami Or use `texdef -t latex TeX LaTeX`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to get “LaTeX” symbol in document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7546/5764) or [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) (or any other TeX-related logo)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764).

Comment: @Werner I don't think it is -- this isn't using something existing, it's making something new. Certainly related, but not a dupe, I'd say.

Comment: ...poor question, regardless.

Comment: @Werner It could stand for improvement. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17886/17423

Comment: Can you extend your question a bit, add some detail to it, some explanation. When i first read the question, i had no clue what you mean. I bet others felt the same.

Comment: I'm bewildered really, in what way is the question at all unclear? the OP wants to be able to type a name with offset letters like the latex logo, as it says in the question title. I voted to re-open.

Comment: I voted to reopen.  I was disappointed to see it closed.  I hope to see many more creative responses.  Such a fun question!

Comment: @A.Ellett -- maybe it should get a `[fun]` tag?

Comment: Thank you very much for the efforts!  your editing, comments and critics were all very appreciated!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14):

this requires xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\XeTeXcharclass`L=4
\XeTeXcharclass`A=4
\XeTeXcharclass`T=4
\XeTeXcharclass`E=4
\XeTeXcharclass`X=4
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 4{\z}
\def\z#1{{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 0\lowercase{\,#1}}}

\lccode`L=`D
\lccode`T=`V
\lccode`E=`I
\lccode`X=`D


\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: XD *nice*. If I'm not mistaken, this maps the LaTeX glyphs onto the letters in your name :) Cheeky.

Comment: that's a rather scrawny "a". would look better as a small cap (or a "smaller" cap) since the slope of "A" nicely mirrors the slope of the "V".  maybe if you ask nicely, i'll concoct a prettier version for you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It has to fit into the offsets designed for the original \LaTeX, I don't think Jonathan quite had this in mind when designing xetex char classes.

Comment: if you want to laugh, you can look up what we've done to get a sloped xetex for tugboat.  now *that*'s a real kludge!

Answer (score 14):

You can write *your* name creatively as I do mine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newsavebox{\mynamebox}

\savebox{\mynamebox}{%%
        $\Lambda\mspace{-13mu}-\mspace{-5mu}%%
         \cdot\mspace{-0.25mu}%%
         \xi\mspace{-1mu}^{\parallel}\mspace{-3mu}%%
         \epsilon^{\mspace{-2mu}\dagger\mspace{-5mu}\dagger}$}%%

\begin{document}

\usebox\mynamebox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooohh... Pretty :)

Answer (score 11):

Best way to find out how the `\TeX` logo works is to look at `\meaning\TeX`.  Since `\LaTeX` is protected, you need to use `\expandafter\meaning\csname LaTeX \endcsname`.  `texdef` is a tool you can use on the command line to quickly look these things up: `texdef -t latex TeX LaTeX [... more macros ...]`.

Among other font-selection commands, the logos use `\kern` and `\raisebox` to fine-tune the horizontal/vertical position of each character.  For (a bad) example:

```
AL\kern-3pt\relax\raisebox{1.5pt}{L}\kern-3pt\relax
\raisebox{3pt}{R}\kern-7.33pt\relax
\raisebox{-5pt}{E}\kern-1pt\relax D
```

Comment: `\meaning\TeX` yes `\meaning\LaTeX` no

Comment: @touhami See edit

Comment: Did you mean to forget your `F`?

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't have an F. :)

Comment: OMG.... I've been reading your name wrong for too too long.  How embarassing.

Comment: if you examine the tex and latex logos carefully, you will observe that they won't spread adjacent lines apart, since they don't greatly exceed the depth of the usual descender in the current font.  and neither of them rises higher than the cap height.  for the (quite highly tuned for computer modern) definition of `\LaTeX` et al., look into `ltugboat.cls`.  for a somewhat "simpler" (to comprehend) definition, see the plain tex `tugboat.cmn` (on ctan and in tex live).

Answer (score 11):

Based on my SX logo, which uses the `\S` sectioning glyph as my initials.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Huge\scalebox{3.8}{\S}\kern-.5ex\bfseries\LARGE\setstackgap{L}{1.35\baselineskip}%
\Centerstack[l]{te\kern2pt\tclap[5pt]{v}\kern2pt{}en egl\tclap[12pt]{t}e\bclap[10pt]{s}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is my SX logo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\def\rl{\rule{2.05ex}{0ex}}
\fboxrule=2pt
\fbox{\rl\stackinset{c}{}{b}{3.65ex}{\LARGE\bfseries B}{\scalebox{4}{\S}}\rl}
\end{document}
```

which is my stackexchange icon, and initials: SBS, obtained by overlaying a "B" atop the LaTeX section symbol `\S` (Computer Modern).

[image]

Comment: Another example: `\input opmac \ooalign{\S\cr \thefontscale[180]\hfil \raise2.4ex\hbox{B}\hfil\cr} \bye`.

Comment: @wipet What?? No `\pdfliteral`?!

Comment: \pdfliteral seems to be more complicated: `\ooalign{\S\cr \hfil \raise.43ex
 \hbox to0pt{\pdfliteral{q .2 0 0 .2 0 0 cm}\hss\bf B\hss\pdfliteral{Q}}\hfil\cr}`

Comment: @wipet I tip my hat to you!

Answer (score 2):

It requires a bit / lot of manual adjusting, but I am using this one since, well, forever:

```
\def\RGtti{R\kern-0.3em\raise-0.6ex\hbox{G}\kern-0.1em\hbox{tti}}
```

...and I have a fully-linked version too (more manual adjusting)...

```
\def\RGttiC{\hbox{\strut R\kern-0.3em\raise-0.6ex\hbox{G}\kern-0.15em%
    \hbox{t\kern-0.08em t\kern-0.05em i}%
    \kern-0.7em\raise0.935ex\hbox{\vrule height 0.07ex depth 0pt width 0.5em}%
    \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 0.2em}
}
```

[image]