# Can someone help me modify the LaTeX logo so I can cut it out from a board of wood?

Tags: fonts, typography

Some modifications are shown here:
https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91murzynowski-logo.pdf

I have a flat 3/4" board. I'd like a heavy bold logo with all letters connected that is displayed in landscape so it can be printed and traced.

I'll post the final wooden word when it's finished.

UPDATE: Here it is. http://m.imgur.com/3EAFM6I

I'll post an album showing the process once I make some final adjustments. It broke in two places, which I epoxied.

Comment: Of interest here: [How could I write my name, for example, to look like the \LaTeX logo?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244812)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I was instructed to not use my own name.

Comment: are you selling those?

Comment: Wasn't planning on it, but if enough people are interested and would pay a reasonable price I suppose I could do a small Kickstarter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the original design is not connected, something has to give. I have used the LModern Bold 12pt font to create the LaTeX logo, imported it into Adobe Illustrator, outlined it, and fudged "L" and "A" such that all letters are connected.

[image]

I don't know how to share the PDF but send me an email at lindig@gmail.com and I'm happy to send you the PDF or an [SVG](https://gist.github.com/lindig/e7f4f0042f194b34a8bb) file. The logo is printed on DIN A4 in landscape and about 25cm x 9cm in size.

*Addendum*: the [SVG file](https://gist.github.com/lindig/e7f4f0042f194b34a8bb) for the logo  on Gist/GitHub.

Comment: I think using `\raise` and friends will lead to a similar output, without the need of expensive software.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll see if anyone else has an idea for a thicker line option, otherwise I'll take on this challenge. I think scaling the image and printing it will work fine since it's just to get the overall outline.

Comment: @Johannes_B I used Illustrator to create a PDF that doesn't rely on embedded fonts but only uses vector outlines. This is easier to feed into plotting software. How would you do this with the standard TeX tool chain?

Comment: I'd use inkscape instead of illustrator, not part of the standard LaTeX toolchain but FOSS, cross-platform and widely used by LaTeX users.  The net effect would be the same (also @Johannes_B).

Comment: It is physically impossible to saw this from wood. The connections are way too tiny and fragile. The A breaks from the L before you even finish it. Unfortunately if you' d saw each character individually it is almost impossible to mend them together without seeing the glue line. It might even be better to saw each character individually and glue it on a background. Either white or transparent and not try to have an invisible glue line. Intended visible is better than unintended visible.

Comment: I agree that this is not a good fit for wood but it is how I understood the question. I don't know about the project but I can see these solutions: stay with the original logo, cut letters from thick wood or styrofoam and mount them on a plate, or cut letters from thin wood (or metal, or plastic) and mount them raised on a plate. It all depends on the application.

Comment: Updated description with a link to the word.