# How do I get a BibTeX logo?

Tags: symbols, logos

I know how to use `\LaTeX` to get a fancy version of the word LaTex; I’ve seen a similar version of the spelling of BibTeX but `\BibTeX` doesn’t work. I’ve tried a few variants on capitalization and not hit on one that works.

The problem with searching about anything to do with BibTeX is there are so many articles on how to use it that this specific question does not show up in queries.

It [*ought* to be possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) to do this:

[image: BiBTeX fancy rendering]

Comment: This answer shows how `\LaTeX` is defined, and thus how you could create your own command: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244814/215

Comment: I couldn’t find this question before searching for 'BibTeX symbol'. Changing the question to 'How do I get a BibTeX logo?' is not actually helpful because it makes it equally unfindable :( – sometimes people searching for something do not know the canonical keyword. But thanks for the answers …

Answer (score 4):

The `ltugboat` class defines `\BibTeX` similarly to

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BibTeX}{{\normalfont\scshape Bib\kern-0.08em \TeX}}
```

It's up to you deciding whether to allow the logo respecting the current font attributes, at the risk of not getting “Bib” in small caps.

The definition in `btxdoc.tex` (Oren Patashnik's manual), is

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

that, in modern form, would be

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BibTeX}{%
  {\normalfont B\kern-.05em{\scshape i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em \TeX}%
}
```

Here's the output from the two definitions (in the same order)

[image]

Comment: What value should I use for the last `\kern` if I replace `\TeX` by `\LaTeX`? I think there is no rule, right?

Comment: @Sigur Experiment and choose; anyway, there is no “official” logo for `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2):

For Computer/Latin Modern roman (serif) font faces, I've had good experience with the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{\textsc{B\kern-0.1emi\kern-0.017emb}\kern-0.15em\TeX}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{\textsc{B\kern-0.1emi\kern-0.017emb}\kern-0.15em\TeX}
\begin{document}
\obeylines  % just for this example
\tiny\BibTeX
\scriptsize\BibTeX
\footnotesize\BibTeX
\small\BibTeX
\normalsize\BibTeX
\large\BibTeX
\Large\BibTeX
\huge\BibTeX
\Huge\BibTeX
\end{document}
```