# How to write text in style LaTeX is written?

Tags: xetex, kerning

I want to write text not in English but some other font and language  in same manner as \LaTeX writes. i.e. some characters are raised some low, with kerning and all that. I am using XeTeX since I have to work with other language. [image: thats what I want to achieve]

Comment: `\raisebox{2pt}{whatever}`?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Probably a bigger question than is able to be answered here.  _What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner_: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/90087 is probably what you might be looking for. To the extent that is true, this might be a duplicate question.

Comment: Similar too http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244812/how-could-i-write-my-name-for-example-to-look-like-the-latex-logo

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks its is working to raise the letters but I can't lower them down with -ve value. although documentation says it can work with -ve value.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for response, I tried all the ways as mentioned in referred post. They are fine as long as I run them as it is. when I try to run them for arabic the language I have to work with it is giving the error  "! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly."

Comment: Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)