# reStructuredText logo in LaTeX

Tags: restructured-text

I would like to refer to reStructuredText in my LaTeX documents my using an equivalent of the \LaTeX{} command. Has anybody perhaps created one?

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313527/

Comment: `\newcommand\rest{reStructuredText}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I assume the OP wants up/down letters :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The only logo-like thing I've found for reStructuredText is the one at the top of http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html, which at best requires some font changes and kerning. I think one usually just writes reStructuredText. That said, it might not hurt if johzi described in a bit more detail exactly what the desired output would be.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I agree 100 %.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, @TorbjørnT. and Manual. Manuel did get the gist of what I needed, though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/)'s commend
>   (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Quick and Dirty
% I do not know enough about kerning to make it (even) prettier :).
% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313527 for example or https://ctan.org/pkg/metalogo.

\newcommand{\myReStTe}{\textit{\textrm{re}}\texttt{Structured}\textit{\textrm{Text}}}
% Maybe use \providecommand if you plan to use a more plain macro name which is more likely to be alreday taken by another package or document class (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36175).

\begin{document}

\myReStTe

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Hint:** Maybe have a look at the `xspace` package to avoid needing the `{}` after the command, as in `Before \LaTeX{} After`.

Comment: Why the `\textrm`, which does nothing?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In case the command is used in a sans serif context.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for the noise.