# Scale a letter but it keeps the original space

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, boxes

```
La\scale{T}eX is a high-quality typesetting system; 
it includes features designed for the production of technical and scientific documentation. LaTeX is the de facto standard for the communication and publication of scientific documents. LaTeX is available as free software.
```

I want to have a `\scale` command so that the letter occupies its original space, then rendered as a larger one, like twice bigger.

I'm happy to use pgf/tikz and it's like the `overlap` and `transform canvas` options but these options don't keep the original space.

I guess I could have two T. One T is white so it's invisible, and the other T is overlap. But I feel it's cumbersome. Are there any better ways?

[image: a letter is twice bigger but keeps its original space]

Comment: We assume that you are aware of [`\LaTeX` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7546/241755)!!

Comment: @C.F.G Yes, I do. It's better if I can do something like `\La\scale{T}eX`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have some doubts that this count as good typography:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

La\makebox[\fontcharwd\font `T]{\scalebox{2}{T}}eX is a high-quality 
typesetting 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you vertically center it? Notice my stroke is beyond the baseline.

Comment: @Gqqnbig "\raisebox{-0.5\fontcharht\font \`T}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font \`T]{\scalebox{2}{T}}}" ? (grrr, no way to quote backticks here)

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is strange La\phantom{T}\clap{\hspace{-0.6em}\raisebox{-0.6ex}{\huge T}}eX and this in normal \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

[image: Text with LaTeX logo]

Comment: It looks like we still need two T. One T is to take space, and the other T is scaled.